# Azure ReservedIP Bad Request on old Windows VM isntance

Tags: azure, ip

I am using Azure Powershell cmdlets to reserve the current IP of my running Windows VM instance. To test it, I created a new VM, ran it up, then ran New-AzureReservedIP with the -ServiceName tack so it knows reserve teh current IP. It worked a charm! I shut down the machine and it reallocaed the same IP address on startup.

Now if I do the exact same thing on an actual production Windows VM I get the below error. Could it be that this machine has been running for about 3 years and is not supported for some reason? Syntax is correct as my initial test and in the same location etc..

BadRequest : Cannot reserve the ip of deployment xxxxxxxx

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this cloud service is 3 years old it is quite possible that you are using an affinity-group VNET to host the VM. It is not possible to reserve an IP address from such a VNET. The following is [documented](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/):

```
Reserved IPs are only supported in regional VNets. It is not supported for VNets that are associated with affinity groups. For more information about associating a VNet with a region or an affinity group, see [About Regional VNets and Affinity Groups][2].
```